# Duda con Toolbar en Android

Tags: android, toolbar

estoy estudiando Android, pero me surgió esta duda.

¿Por que cuando agregamos una Toolbar a una activity desde su XML, debemos luego decirle llamar a "setSupportActionBar(toolbar);"?

¿En caso de que quiera agregar una segunda Toolbar tengo que volver a llamar a ese método?

La verdad que no me queda claro eso.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

no entendi muy bien tu pregunta pero si no sabes bien como usar un ToolBar, ahi te va una ayudadita:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater ().inflate ( R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId ();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.Cerrar) {
        fondo= new Fondo ();
        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().add ( R.id.content_main, fondo ).commit ();
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.Scan){
        Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext (), Scanner.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected ( item );
}
// </editor-fold>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dato:

Recuerda que el android actual te trae ayuda, así es que es mas fácil de hacerlo, de otra manera los tutoriales son de mucha ayuda :)

Comment: @Bloom es mejor responder con código y no con capturas de pantalla. Para organizar el código, selecciona el código y presiona [ctrl] + [k]. Mira [esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.